# Program that uses While and For loops to find all Prime Numbers between an upper Bound

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm having some trouble with the for loop. I have the while loop working properly, but I need help with the nested loop. The concept of loops is fairly new to me and I don't quite understand what I've done here in the code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var number = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter number: ", ""));
var divisor;
var check;
var prime = true;
var num;

document.write("The factors of ", number, " are: </br>");
divisor = 1;

while (divisor <= number) {
    check = number % divisor;
    if (check == 0) {
        document.write(divisor, " ");
        if ((divisor != 1) && (divisor != number)) {
            prime = false;
        }
    }

    divisor = divisor + 1;
}

if (prime == true) {
    document.write("<br>The number is prime");
} else {
    document.write("<br> The number is composite");
}
```

Comment: I don't know what you did either. What is giving you trouble?

Comment: Off topic, but you only need to check up to the square root of the number, not the number itself.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test

Answer (score 0):

Something to get you excited. This program is using for and while to check prime numbers. The for loop is used as an if-check but this will work. You should also try using functions to minimize your code.

```
var number = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter number: ", ""));
var result = isPrime(number);

function isPrime(number) {
    var start = 2;
    //USING WHILE
    while (start <= Math.sqrt(number)) {
       if (number % start++ < 1) return false;
    }
    return number > 1;
}

//USING FOR 
for (;result;){ 
   document.write("<br>The number is prime");
}
if(!result) {
   document.write("<br>The number is NOT prime");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a fresh man,I think may you need a break in the while loop,beacause you just check if it is prime once.Just like that:

```
if((divisor != 1) && (divisor != number)){
prime= false;
break;
}
```

Comment: Although this means the output no longer includes a list of all the divisors.

Comment: Yes..But if just for check,it is ok